# Alternate color changes its position during scrolling in dynamic listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

```
if (convertView == null) {
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dtl_grid, parent, false);

        //  vh.llMain = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sdg_ll_main);
            if (pos % 2 == 0) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A4A4A4"));
            } else{
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            }
```

I have tried the above code in adapter The list is coming with alternate color but when we scroll down the color changes its position like first they are coming grey white grey white but after scrolling it up or down it comes grey grey white grey white white like that , i have searched this many solution are given in that they are saying to add else part for second color i have already done that but still no success. Please provide me wih a good solution. thanks

Comment: put your condition outside of your outer if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `ViewHolder`pattern in a `ListView` (something that you should do) you have to understand it first.

Android reuses the views you have already inflated. So you have to distinguish two scenarios:

- The view you are using is not inflated
- The view you are using is some one you already inflated and is being reused

In the first case you have to inflate the view, create a `ViewHolder` and set it as the view's tag.

In the second case the only thing you have to do is recover the `ViewHolder` object.

After that, work with the `ViewHolder`. Take a look at [this example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).

In your concrete case, the solution will be something like:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    inflateView(...);
    createViewHolder(...);
} else {
    recoverViewHolder(...);
}

if (pos % 2 == 0) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A4A4A4"));
} else{
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
}
```

Comment: `"When you use the ViewHolderpattern in a ListView (something that you should do) you have to understand it first."` View holder pattern is not so important but in most cases people has problems in implementing it, note that none of standard google's adapters use view holder pattern (yes: none of 5 adapter class that extend `BaseAdapter` doesn't use view holder pattern)

Comment: It is important if you care about optimizing your app. It's true: none of the Google's adapters uses it. BUT with the addition of the `RecyclerView` the game has change. ;)

Comment: we are talking about `ListView` right? view holder pattern in a `ListView` is in 99% useless and only makes your code more complex not adding anything

Comment: @Dr.pelocho.. i got little bit idea of what you saying but not properly get it....   i can send here my full  adapter code .. then can you tell me where to do changes.. and thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, we're talking about `ListView`. Implementing the View Holder pattern doesn't necessarily make your code more complex. It's just a question of how you code. About the pattern being useless... I disagree. Let's see what [Google says](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Comment: first: if it was so important as they say so why didn't they introduced view holder pattern in their `BaseAdapter` adapters? second: read this http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html (i did some measurements and, when using view holder pattern, i saved 1 ms or something when scrolling a list view with 100 items from the top to the bottom, yes **ONE** millisecond)

Comment: If it wasn't introduced in `BaseAdapter` adapters but it was in `RecyclerView.Adapter` I assume it was due to backward compatibility. You say that you saved one millisecond. We'd have to see how many `inflate()` and `findViewById()` methods have been called. Are you against the pattern due to "code complexity"? OK, don't use it. But usually how complex the code is depends on the coder

Comment: `inflate` has nothing to do with "view holder pattern", with or without "view holder pattern" `inflate()` is called the same number of times, seems that you dont completly understand how this stuff works

Comment: With the `ViewHolder` pattern `inflate()` is called once per displayed view (let's call that number `dv`) and `findViewById()` once per view accessed (let's call that number `av`). So the total number of callls would be `dv*av`. Both `dv` and `dv*av` **remains constant**. Without the pattern both numbers grow as the user goes up and down through the list

Comment: so you think if the ListView can display 10 items at once and the adapter has 10000 items, then without view holder pattern the number of `inflate()` calls would be 10000 when scrolling from top to bottom? or 10000 - 10? or something else?

Comment: If the `ListView` can display 10 items it will firstly call `inflate()` 10 times. Every time you display another item it will call `inflate()` again. So, for example, when the previous `ListView` shows the 11th item it will call `inflate()` again. When you come back to the first element it will call `inflate()` again as the `getView()` method is called every time a `View` needs to be painted. Having 1000 elements and scrolling from top to bottom will make 1000 calls. Scrolling back to top will make another 1000 - 10

Comment: yes, this is what i thought: you are mixing up "view reusing" and "view holder pattern", but dont worry 90% of folks do the same: see for example ArrayAdapter: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#358, here `getView` calls directly `createViewFromResource`, now copy that sources to your project and add `Log.d` in the line 371 (where mInflater.inflate is called) and you will see that inflate is called max 10 times (or 11 in the worst case) no matter how many items you have in the adapter, and of course there is no view holder here